# Understanding social networks API limits

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, twitter-oauth, instagram

I couldn't figure out a very strange thing that i see in the Instagram and Twitter API limits.
It seems that your user base can't exceed a very LOW limit, and than your app will just be blocked because limits are `per app` .

**Instagram** :
Per app, you have 5000 requests per hour(Auth/or not) .
see here : http://instagram.com/developer/limits/

That means if my app created in instagram,which has client ID, is making a call on behalf of a mobile user- that will be counted as 1 call -so i can't have more than **5000 users per hour using my app with my client id** ??

**Twitter**
from the API limit doc :

> If user A launches application Z, and app Z makes 10 calls to user A’s
>   mention timeline in a 15 minute window, then app Z has 5 calls left to
>   make for that window

can find here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting

That means that if i created an app in Twitter, and my mobile user request his time line, so i can only have **15 active users in 15 minutes** ?

**I dont know if i miss something big here, or that the whole API is just worthless, you can't do anything big(or medium) with 15 users in 15 minutes, or even 5000 users per hour.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misinterpret things...

**Instagram** is stating

> - Authenticated Calls:    5,000 / hour per token
> - Unauthenticated Calls   5,000 / hour per application

As you normally will HAVE to use authenticated calls to get user information, I think 5000 per **Access Token** (User) per hour should be more than enough.

**Twitter** is stating that

> Rate limiting in version 1.1 of the API is primarily considered on a **per-user** basis — or more accurately described, **per access token** in your control. If a **method** allows for 15 requests per **rate limit window**, then it allows you to make 15 requests per window per leveraged access token.

The rate window is considered as 15min. This doesn't mean that you can only make 15 requests per Access Token in 15min, but e.g. 15 requests to `GET account/settings` per Access Token per 15min. See 
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i still dont understand, instagram say : The API limit is 5000 requests per hour per access_token or client_id . so if they say "or", that means when the first one of them is meet the condition. so access-token will probably not make 5000 per user, but the client ID which is one for all my users, will definitely reach 5000 for 5000 users.. what am i missing ?

Comment: ok , think i got it for instagram. I hope i am getting it right. but what i am curious about, is why should they let me have so much, so i can just copy their own app, and make my own ? what is their interest ?